# Calendar_Date_Select rails-- noneditable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using calendar_date_select for the date in my application..

```
<% calendar_date_select :start_date %>
```

I am using like this when the `controller.action_name=="new"`.

For the `controller.action_name=="edit"` I am displaying the date like this

```
<% calendar_date_select :start_date, @date, :pop_up => "force" %>
```

Here @date means start_date value, I am retrieving from database, using as @date.

Actually date is displaying, and I can edit the date.

But for particular stage I should not edit the date. I tried to search calendar_date_select non-editable. Is there any way not to edit the date using calendar_date_select.

Please suggest me If there are any other alternatives.. for this..

Comment: If you don't want it to be editable at a certain stage (assuming by stage you have an `if` block or something on `action_name==new/edit`) then why not just display the date with `to_formatted_s` or something? Why make it selectable at all?

Comment: Means I should not use pop_up => force for that... ri8? and I have to use that command as `<%calendar_date_select :start_date,@date %>`. Is it ok? Or I need to do any modification for that command and another doubt ,. after this I can't modify the date.. by using the command like that.

Comment: From the docs on that plugin, `:pop_up => 'force`' just disables text input, but doesn't prevent you from editing the value via the pop up. Just display the value with `<%= @date.to_formatted_s %>` if the user shouldn't edit the value...

Comment: Idea is nice.. But I can't display the value normally, because I am using the existing application with some features, it may effect the application design if I am doing like this. So, I want to  display the date in Textbox with read_only=> true. But either value or read_only is possible for textbox.I tried..but I didn't get.Can you help how to display the value in text_box with read_only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the `calendar_date_select` for this, use a normal `text_field_tag`:

```
<%= text_field_tag(:start_date, @date, {readonly: true}) %>
```

That should create a text field with your `@date` value and mark the text field as read-only.